# Using requests module to export csv

Tags: python, export-to-csv, python-requests

I'm a beginner to Python and I have been trying to export my data to a csv file but I can't figure out how to get rid of all the brackets and my comma separated. Ideally I need two columns: one with all values for "count" and one with values for "month".

Any advice appreciated.

My code:

```
from sunlight import capitolwords
import requests
import csv

r = requests.get ('http://capitolwords.org/api/1/dates.json?phrase=guns&start_date=2011-  
12-01&end_date=2013-01-
15&granularity=month&sort=count&apikey=ab02633fb17841d09f4c3660e0384ae5')
data = r.text

ifile = open('guns.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(data.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
    print row
```

Result:

```
  ['{']
  ['    "results": [']
  ['        {']
  ['            "count": 62.0', '']
  ['            "month": "201212"']
  ['        }', '']
  ['        {']
  ['            "count": 36.0', '']
  ['            "month": "201207"']
  ['        }', '']
  ['        {']
  ['            "count": 35.0', '']
  ['            "month": "201112"']
  ['        }', '']
  ['        {']
  ['            "count": 27.0', '']
  ['            "month": "201202"']
  ['        }', '']
  ['        {']
  ['            "count": 27.0', '']
```

Comment: You say you're trying to *export* data, but your code only shows a CSV *reader*. What's up with that? In any case, the first argument for `csv.reader` must be file handle, not a list of strings like in your code.

Answer (score 6):

Since the response is a Json, load the json data with:

```
data = r.json()["results"] # read the json response and keep the results part
```

and then write to the csv file:

```
with open("guns.csv", "wb") as csvfile:
    f = csv.writer(csvfile)
    f.writerow(["Count", "Month"]) # write the headers if you like
    for elem in data:
        f.writerow([elem["count"], elem["month"]])
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add a bit of explanation to what @thikonom has said above.

```
r.json()
```

When you're using r.json(), you're interpreting what is in **r** as **json**. A hint was given to your data being json in the query string you sent. If you're familiar with json, the results also look like json.

```
r.json()["results"]
```

You're now telling json to search your results **r** for the dictionary with the key: **results**. Being able to see what you're expecting from the query is a big help here, where **results** is shown in the results you've pasted into the window above. We also recognize that it's displayed in the standard way that a dictionary is shown:

```
{'results': [{'month': '201212', 'count': 62.0}...
```

and so on. **results** in this case is the **key**, the rest of the data after the **:** is considered the **key's value**. Using ~> r.json()["results"] <~ returns **results** value. However, you'll notice that **'month'** and **'count'** are also wrapped in {}, meaning they are each in themselves key, value pairs. This means you've got dictionaries nested within dictionaries!

```
f.writerow([elem["count"], elem["month"]])
```

Going through, row by row, pulling out the **value** for both keys: **count** and **month**, which you then store into your *.csv file.

Hope this may help somebody else!

Answer (score 2):

if CSV package is not mandatory you can use the normal output operation and save the file with CSV. CSV is just a txt file with cols seperated by comma.

here how you can do this.

```
with open("abc.csv","w+") as fh:
    str = "count: 62.0"

    str = str + ",month: 201212" 

    fh.writeline(str)
```